# Return false on Ajax form not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have a form in that evaluates information in the database on my process page and returns errors if necessary. I'm using Ajax so it shouldnt actually be going to the process page and loading what I have encoded in Json to return. Here is my form plus Javascript:

```
<form method="post" action="../user/process_login" id="login_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
    <label>Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />       
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password1" name="password0" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" placeholder="Submit" class="button"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login_form').submit(function(){
        $.post
        (
            $(this).attr('action'),
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(data){
                if (data['errors'] == '') {
                    consle.log(data);
                };
                else{
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#alert_box').html(data);
                };
            },
            "json"
        );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the relevant section of my validation code:

```
if (count($user) > 0 AND $decrypted_password == $this->input->post('password0')) 
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_session', $user);
        $this->load->view('main.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $errors = "<div class='alert-box alert' id='error-box'><p>Your login information did not match our reccords. Try again</p></div>";
    echo json_encode($errors);
    }
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text.**

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: `$decrypted_password` <-- This shouldn't be possible.  Passwords should be stored using a one-way hash and *not* be decryptable.

Comment: The password isnt stored in plaintext. Thats just a variable i use to compare the stored password. Now that I think of it, I'll reverse that by encrypting the input and comparing it with the stored password.

Comment: @JDillon522: Don't encrypt it, hash it.  It shouldn't be possible to decrypt the password at all.

Comment: either way, thats not the problem. 

When the form submits it goes to the process page, does its work, and instead of the [return false] kicking in it submits the page. I wind up staring at Json on what would be my process page instead of where the form was submitted from

Comment: @SLaks it doesnt show anything in the console because it loads a new page. For some reason the return false isnt working

Comment: @JDillon522 `JSON.parse(data)` before

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because there is an error in your code. I point it out below

Here is without the error ----> [WITHOUT ERRORS](http://jsfiddle.net/jafrisella/m7qa7/)

Here is with the Error   -----> [WITH ERRORS](http://jsfiddle.net/jafrisella/m7qa7/1/)

As you can see the return false does work without errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login_form').submit(function(){
    $.post
    (
        $(this).attr('action'),
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(data){
            if (data['errors'] == '') {
                consle.log(data);
            };   <----------------------- Error Not supposed to be there
            else{
                console.log(data);
                $('#alert_box').html(data);
            };   <----------------------- I think will still work but don't need
        },
        "json"
    );
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: @JDillon522 You mean the code is Still directing you to the page? Do you have jquery script tag on the page?

Comment: @JDillon522 I added another Fiddle at the Top as examples to show that `return false` works. Or `e.preventDefault();`. I tested both. However if you have more code there could be another error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use input type submit, while calling an Ajax function, if you use it, your code will not work as expected, so change it to:

```
<input type="button" id="submitbtn" placeholder="Submit" class="button"/>
```